# fix position expand and cross from right side main div

Tags: css

pikastar dot com is website when scroll down it then fix position on nav menu expand and it > will cross the main div. how can i will fix it.

```
#topNav.sticky {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 #000000;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a event scroll event handler, when scroll position reaches to specific value, add a fixed position to it according to your styling.